# Erratic battery percentage behavior

Tags: ipod-touch, battery

I purchased an iPod Touch in December 2011. It came with a Target 2 year warranty. From the time I started using it the battery never read correctly. I decided before the warranty was up in February 2013 to send it in for repair. They returned it and said they replaced the battery. It still does not read correctly.

I have done backup and restores as well as full wipes without restoring the backup. Upgraded OS. Currently it is jailbroken but it performs this way with the jailbreak installed or not.

I installed a cydia package that displays the actual battery health and it says the design capacity is 930 and currently it is at 859. So I dont think its a bad battery. I have uploaded a [video to YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bAmcW_bF74I) to show the issue.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: That video was spooky. I wonder what Apple said once they see that.. besides the music was animating too.
Do you live close to a genius bar by any chance? You should take a picture of their faces once you display this to them.. Sorry I have no solution for this ghost in your iPod..

Comment: haha, thanks for the laugh. I had some background noise while i was recording, so i used the stock youtube soundtracks. this one seemed appropriate. ;) closest genius bar is about an two hours away. might be cheaper to buy another ipod. :(

Comment: On the video it looks as if the battery runs down extremely fast, so it may not be the battery but rather something else inside the iPod which causes that. As you are out of warranty, a new iPod might be the best option (or a trip to the store and hope for a discount on a new one).

Comment: any clues as to what that something else is? i'm not afraid to pull it apart to replace parts if necessary. when they replaced the battery, is it possible they only replace the battery or is the battery attached to the motherboard?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a n00b so can't reply to your comment, but can hopefully give some more details in this answer.

Yes, the battery on the 4th gen touch (assuming that's the correct model) is soldered to the board. It would be interesting to know what Target did, as Apple don't do actual repairs on iPods - it would have been replaced like-for-like under their warranty. The fact that you're having the same issue persisting after the battery was replaced, and you've ruled out software by restoring would obviously suggest something else as you mentioned. There's not much in the way of diagnosis avaliable for these but I'd guess that it's likely to be an issue with the power management IC on the board.

If you're experienced with BGA work, this could probably be replaced, but it would be easier to replace the board if you can get hold of one, or to be honest just replacing the iPod in this case I think. Depending on the storage size, an out of warranty swap from Apple is maybe around $100 if you're in the US (90 day warranty), or they should give you around 15% off a new one in-store if you give it to them for recycling and buy a new one. Lastly, you could of course punt it on eBay or the like and get a new one.

Hope that's of some help.